# Получение координат из GeoObjectCollection

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Я строю маршрут двумя разными способами: 
1)

```
routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function (route) {
    route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function () {
        var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
        if (activeRoute) {
         var pathsObjects  = ymaps.geoQuery(activeRoute.getPaths()),
        console.log(pathsObjects.getLength ()); Результат 0.
```

2)

```
ymaps.route([[59.933111, 30.300493], [59.900703, 30.720720]]).then(
        function (res) {
            var pathsObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(res.getPaths()),
         console.log(pathsObjects.getLength ()); Результат 1.
```

И в одном и в другом случае методу ymaps.geoQuery передается объект GeoObjectCollection но результат возвращается только в одном случае, хотя на карте маршруты строятся. Результат я хочу в дальнейшем использовать для получекния координат, и дальнейшей обработки попадания координат в полигоны. И статическое задание координат (как во втором случае) мне не подходит. А получить результат из маршрута, построенного из routePanelControl (первый вариант) не получается. Подскажите где ошибка или способ получения координат из multiRouter.MultiRoute?

Answer (score 1):

у модели мультимаршрута есть метод getJson который вернет GeoJson с описанием маршрута. Из этого объекта можно получить всю геометрию мультимаршрута. К примеру:

```
multiRoute.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function (e) {
  console.log(multiRoute.model.getJson());
});
```

Comment: Метод getJson мне известен, аналогичен getAllPoints() - результат приблизительно одинаковый. Оба эти метода возвращают  WayPoint & ViaPoint - фактически начало и конец маршрута. А для проверки какая часть маршрута попадет в полигон необходимы координаты каждой точки маршрута. getPaths преданный в GeoGuery как раз и должен возвращать массив из которого методом each (в цикле методом  path.geometry.getCoordinates) можно извлечь все координа маршрута. Может быть есть еще какие то идеи или варианты? Спасибо!